# How to dispatch an event to all scripts?

Tags: php

I'm developing a simple plugin system with php just for learning reasons. I have a question but I can't think of a solution. So, what I'm trying to do basically is dispatch an "event" and hook it in another script. What I mean by that is: suppose I've a file called "load.php", a folder called "plugins" with three files inside called "plugin1.php", "plugin2.php" and "plugin3.php" respectively.

Once I open the load.php page, I want to dispatch an event named, say, "init".

```
<?php

# dispatch the event
call('init');

?>
```

When that happens, I want all the "plugins/plugin*.php" or any other script that hooked the "init" event to perform some action.

```
# plugins/plugin1.php
<?php

on('init', function() {
    echo 'register plugin 1<br>';
});


?>

# plugins/plugin2.php
<?php

on('init', function() {
    echo 'register plugin 2<br>';
});


?>

# plugins/plugin3.php
<?php

on('init', function() {
    echo 'register plugin 3<br>';
});


?>
```

Desired output when opening load.php:

```
register plugin 1
register plugin 2
register plugin 3
```

How would I do that with plain php and without needing to include all the scripts in the load.php page?
I hope I have explained myself well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is an "event bus", so definitely search for that term to get some ideas about how to do what you want to do. It's a very commonly used design pattern and there is a lot of code out there you can look to for inspiration, or just use directly.

However you will need to either include those plugin files directly in your load.php page, or have some more sophisticated method of getting that code into your execution context. Search for "class loading" and "inversion of control".

You may want to explore application frameworks like Laravel or Symfony, which make this kind of thing easier, or include support for events out of the box or with plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will do some research and post the result after.